# How to reuse RegEx in PhpStorm

Tags: string, phpstorm

I use RegEx to do some common find and replace tasks in PhpStorm. Is there any way to save and reuse the regular expression and replacement string to use later?

Comment: PhpStorm remembers the last 20 search (and replace) patterns  that you've used. Simply click on the icon of the magnifying glass (in the search and replace dialog) to see a dropdown appear with your history. Click it to re-select it.

Comment: Oh, it just remembers the last 20 for me always. Even after restarts. Maybe that's a setting somewhere, but I'm not sure.

Comment: My bad, it keeps the last 20 ones. However I need a better persistent alternative.